# using Excel to calculate sine of an angle

Tags: trigonometry

According to this chart http://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/sine-cosine-tangent-chart.php, the sine of 45 degree angle is 0.70711, something that I also confirmed by looking elsewhere.

I'm trying to learn how to use Excel to calculate this type of math. I did

> =SIN(45)

and it gave me the result 0.850. Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It takes radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the degrees to radians, since Excel takes radians. In this case, $45^\circ=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.